# Como exibir dados dinamicamente no JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing

Eu estou fazendo um pequeno software para apostas e estou completamente perdido em conseguir alocar dados dinamicamente na minha interface de maneira que para cada entrada no banco de dados fosse exibida uma estrutura com um `JPanel` que terá componentes dentro dele e dados do banco, adicionalmente vou precisar manipular esses dados. Gostaria que alguém me orientasse dando um dica de que tipo de estrutura posso usar para fazer isso. Desde já agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo celular não dava mas agora consegui inserir a imagem. Então, eu queria que fossem automaticamente gerados painéis nesse modelo dependendo das entradas da tabela designada no banco. Sendo assim eu iria conseguir recuperar do banco dados como nome do campeonato, nome dos times, data da partida, hora da partida e cotações das modalidades de aposta. Gostaria então de exibir esses dados nesse formato ou até mesmo em um formato mais adequado. O que vou precisar fazer é selecionar qual partida pretendo marcar para aposta e a sua cotação, feito isso preciso pegar o valor das cotações da partida selecionada e então multiplicar pelo valor da aposta do usuário. Dicas?

Vou fazer essa edição para melhorar a visualização.

[Classe cadastrar campeonato](http://pastebin.com/vBSQxhNF)
[image: Interface - Cadastrar Campeonato]

[Classe cadastrar partida](http://pastebin.com/63NyDfhu)
[image: Interface - Cadastrar Partida]

[image: Interface - Cadastrar aposta]

Obs: Na classe cadastrar aposta não tem método nenhum, só tem a interface mesmo. Eu gostaria de recuperar os dados do banco de dados e exibir automaticamente no formato que se encontra no JPanel. Eu estou conseguindo sim fazer as operações no banco de dados, minha dúvida é como fazer pra exibir esses dados de forma automatizada na tela.

Comment: Tente explicar melhor, está muito confuso o que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Eu editei a pergunta e coloquei mais algumas informações. Espero que dê pra entender um pouco melhor agora.

Comment: Você já faz conexão ao banco de dados? Mostre o que já tem feito, sem código fica muito difícil de ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado pelo interesse em ajudar, coloquei mais alguns detalhes do código. PS: Eu sei que o código não está padronizado mas eu só preciso que isso funcione já que vai ser de utilização em bem curto prazo.

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho, tente evitar colocar muitas imagens, torina difícil a leitura. Até porque essas imagens não são necessárias para o entendimento da pergunta. Outra coisa, tente focar num problema específico, colocar todo seu código no pastebin e postar o link de nada irá adiantar, ninguém vai parar ler todo o fonte do seu projeto. No começo é complicado usar o site, mas não desista. Dê uma lida em [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para aprender como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável